# How can I diff two long lines from the same buffer?

Tags: ediff, diff

When I run tests for my projects, failing tests produce output that looks something like this:

```
        expected: "..."
         but got: "..."
```

The `"..."` are *long* lines that often only have small differences.

How can I quickly diff lines like this?

I've tired copying the lines to separate buffers and using `ediff-buffers`, but that had a few downsides:

- the diff is line-oriented in a way that works poorly for comparing two long lines
- `ediff` messes up my window configuration, so I either need to spawn a new frame or save my current configuration in a register—in practice, this disrupts my workflow a bit
- `ediff` uses a separate frame for its controls, which is awkward when I'm running Emacs as a full-screen application in macOS
- doing this manually is pretty laborious

I could solve the last problem by wrapping this up into an Elisp function, but the other issues would remain. Is there some way to configure `ediff` or use some other diff function that would work better for this usecase?

Answer (score 10):

- Split the window.
- In each window, put point at the start of one of the two lines (or at the start of each `"..."` in your example).
- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `compare-windows` <kbd>RET</kbd>
- <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd><kbd>z</kbd>... to repeatedly compare as many times as necessary.

Or of course, bind `compare-windows` to a key (I use <kbd>C-M-=</kbd>), and you can just type that repeatedly.

---

There's also <kbd>M-x</kbd> `ediff-regions-wordwise`

(I find the set-up process for this awkward by comparison, but YMMV.)

---

> ediff messes up my window configuration, so I either need to spawn a new frame or save my current configuration in a register—in practice, this disrupts my workflow a bit

Put `(winner-mode 1)` in your config, and then you can simply <kbd>C-c</kbd><kbd><left></kbd> (repeatedly, if necessary) to undo the window config changes.

---

> ediff uses a separate frame for its controls, which is awkward when I'm running Emacs as a full-screen application in macOS

Yes, I find that to be a bad default, personally.  It tends to break badly with tiling window managers, and it can be noticeably slower due to the need to create a new frame.  You can fix this with:

```
(setq ediff-window-setup-function #'ediff-setup-windows-plain)
```

---

I recommend that you <kbd>M-x</kbd> `customize-group` <kbd>RET</kbd> `ediff` <kbd>RET</kbd>

Comment: Related Q&A: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56341164

Answer (score 3):

Some user options (a.k.a. parameters) are initialized for a mouse-driven session. It may be worthwhile to note that Ediff may be customized using `ediff-customize`.

**First**, [as mentioned by @phils](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/51429/19761), you should **customize the variable** `ediff-window-setup-function` e.g. `M-x customize-variable`. Set this variable to "***Single Frame***" by clicking on the button <kbd>Value Menu</kbd>, then press the key <kbd>2</kbd> and finally saves the setting using the button <kbd>Apply and Save</kbd>.

The function `ediff-regions-wordwise` can act on different regions **in the same buffer**. Therefore, you just need to select the different regions consecutively.

Press `C-g` if you need to deactivate the preselected region. To mark a region, press `C-SPC` to activate the mark and then move the cursor. As indicated, you should "submit" the active region using `C-M-c`.

Concerning the frame configuration, I think that you should set the variable `ediff-before-setup-hook`. You may also look at `ediff-hook` using `M-x customize-group`.

Note: I find that the user manual is of no help for your issue. It may be worthwhile to know that `C-u M-x ediff-windows-wordwise` compares the windows without user selections if the frame already contains the corresponding windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about your "messes up" problems, but you can do this:

You can use `C-x 4 n n` (command `ni-narrow-to-region-indirect-other-window`) from library [Narrow Indirect](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/NarrowIndirect) to create an indirect buffer for each line.  Then put each buffer in `visual-line-mode`.  Then use `ediff` on the buffers.

I don't see the problems you mention, with that.